# how to add libselinux into the openwrt build system?

Tags: embedded-linux, openwrt, busybox, selinux, libselinux

I am building an openwrt system with selinux support.
First I meet the bug that cannot find , during busybox compiling. And then I know that there is a libselinux library needed to build busybox with selinux support.
As I am not very familiar with the openwrt Makefile, I want to know how to add a library in to it? Is there any guide?
Further more, I have really find that the code in selinux github( https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux) is much different with the code I have find in my local linux source in openwrt ("/linux/security/selinux/*"). Why? I know that selinux is already supported in linux2.6. But it seems that I still have to port selinux to linux my self?

This problem has blocked me long time. Any soft of help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I only know SELinux on Debian, but since you mix different things, I will answer the "Why?" part:

- The Linux-Kernel offers an interface via Linux Security Modules (LSM) for SELinux and  [other security modules](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/security) (that is what you see in your "local linux source").
- To manage SELinux and its policies there are some userland tools (that is your github link).
- SELinux policies itself are compiled .pp files which consist of .te/if/fc files and there are ready-to-use rules called [SELinux Reference Policy Project](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/refpolicy/wiki).
- There are some more tools needed to work with SELinux like `fixfiles` and `restorecon` to set the needed labels.

To check if SELinux is already enabled try the command `id -Z` but if you see an error message, the LSM SELinux is not active. I guess it could be possible to activate it with openwrt, because its part of [busybox/config/selinux](https://github.com/openwrt-mirror/openwrt/tree/master/package/utils/busybox/config/selinux), so you could try the command `sestatus` to see if it is enabled.

On Debian one can do `touch /.autorelabel` and reboot to force relabeling the system.

Comment: Thans @andpei, this really helps a lot. Now I know what I have to do is to move the userland tools to openwrt. Besides, only enable selinux in busybox cannot pass compile, it seems that busybox need the header from the libraries in the userland tools.